GoDaddy spf1 record
I have followed this guide https://www.godaddy.com/es/help/enviar-correo-de-formulario-usando-un-servidor-de-retransmision-smtp-953 to be able to send emails because it seems the emails were being blocked (emails sent to exchange).
Now there is this record and this made it work like a charm.

v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all

So that "include:secureserver.net" is allowing me to send emails on behalf of the domain the record was set to. But if someone else is using GoDaddy's severs and uses the relay smtp sever, can they send emails on behalf of the domain I got?

Yes. Hopefully, GoDaddy's devs are competent enough to prevent that from happening.

If you want to run an audit on your mx server to avoid being blocked/banned by some widely used email providers, you can check mxtoolbox.com, DMARC, Reverse DNS, DKIM are some of the basics, you can also check if your ip(s) are being blacklisted

No as Godaddy enforce the protection by checking if you own the domain.
The article you linked talk about having a web form or php mail's function, which the script would run under your account. It's why there is no authentification in the article. The authentification is forced if you use POP3/SMTP client to remontly use the SMTP's server.


I am using WP Maill SMTP Plugin for wordpress and none of the emails were getting delivered to one account. Once I updated that record, either using php's mail function or SMTP (localhost with no authentication), both worked. And now I tested it on another godaddy account which doesn't own the domain and it also worked.

@JoseAdrian Open a godaddy support case then, you can see something break what they specify.
